# Insertar foreign key

Tags: php, mysql

Necesito insertar en una tabla el id de un usuario y el id de las aficiones mediante `php`. El problema es que el usuario puede tener varias aficiones y no logro hacerlo.

```
 $nombreAficiones = join("','", $aficiones); 
 $sql3 = "select IdAficion from aficiones where Nombre IN ('$nombreAficiones')";
 $objbbdd->consulta($sql3);
 while ($idAficiones = $objbbdd->devolverFilas())
 {
     //
 }

 $sql4 = "insert into usuario_aficiones(IdUsuario, IdAficion) values ('$idUsuario', '$idAficiones');";
```

`$sql3` me devuelve los ids de los nombre de las aficiones que le paso en un array. A la hora del hacer el `insert into` a la tabla usuarios_aficiones, no se como se hace.

EJ:

Quiero hacer el `insert into` idusuario = 1 y idaficiones = 1,2

Que en la tabla quede:

```
idusuario | idaficion 
---------------------
     1    |    1 
     1    |    2
```

Answer (score 0):

No funciona así, es un usuario y una afción a la vez.
Tenés que hacer un insert por afición repitiendo el código de usuario y cambiando la afición en cada insert.

Por otro lado estás concatenando como string los datos al query. Esto expone a tu aplicación a QSL Injection, para evitar esto tenés que usar Prepared Statements, que por otro lado, al tener que repetir el mismo query para cada afición, también es más eficiente porque el query se compila una vez en la base de datos.

El insert te quedaría como:

```
$sql4 = "insert into usuario_aficiones(IdUsuario, IdAficion) values (?, ?);"
```

y luego:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql4);
$stmt->bind_param("ii", $idUsuario, $idAficion);

$idUsuario = 'usuario_X';
foreach($aficiones as $unaAficion){
     $idAficion = $unaAficion;
     $stmt->execute();
}
```

Esto es con `mysqli`, para pdo hay que cambiar la sintaxis pero el procedimiento es similar.

Nota `"ss"` en `stmt->bind_param()` indica en orden el tipo de datos de los parametros.
`"s"` es `string`. Pueden ser:

```
i - integer  
d - double  
s - string  
b - BLOB
```

Comment: En el `bind_param`, en vez de `"ss"` debes pasar **`"ii"`**, dado que son valores numéricos los que se van a insertar.